If I hadn't stopped... then if I were to... I could
John, who used to go to the gym with his friend, stopped working out there a year ago and has since become much weaker than he was back then. When his friend tells him about an upcoming competition where he plans to lift 200 kilos, John is unsure whether he should participate. He says sentence A to his friend:
A. If I hadn't stopped working out at the gym a year ago, and were still as strong as I was back then, then if I were to participate in the competition next week, I could lift 200 kilos.
B. I stopped working out at the gym a year ago, so I'm not as strong as I was back then. Therefore, in the unlikely event that I participate in the competition next week, it's unlikely that I'll be able to lift 200 kilos.
Are the bolded tenses used in sentence A correct in the context given? Sentence B is my interpretation of sentence A (each bolded tense in sentence B corresponds to its equivalent in sentence A). Is the information that sentence B conveys encoded in sentence A?
Thanks in advance.

A is grammatical but not at all idiomatic: nobody would use those forms (subjunctive and irrealis "were") in casual speech. B isn't a good paraphrase ("were still as strong" is a separate conterfactual not a statement of fact.)

Yes,  all the counterfactual conditions, such as "if I hadn't stopped working out" and so on, imply that the speaker believes that "I stopped working out" is true. Moreover the speaker believes "I am not as strong" and "I will not participate"
Neither text seems typical of spoken English. The chaining together of multiple unreal and counterfactual conditions is too confusing to be natural English.
